# Google Bigquery error "Multiple definitions of field."

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-node

I'm using the google cloud node library pushing JSON record to a bigquery table.

I'm getting a lot of PartialFailureError with message "Multiple definitions of field."

```
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Multiple definitions of field.",
    "reason": "invalid"
  }
]
```

What does this error mean. I've looked in the row data and compared that to the schema and haven't seen anything strange in terms of repeated fields or duplicate entries.

Comment: can you share with us your schema and an example of a row you are inputting into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that some field (alas error message doesn't say which one), was defined in schema as repeated (i.e. JSON array), but was not repeated - or vice versa.

Comment: I've triple checked in my schema and there is no REPEATED field for this table and there is no arrays in my JSON that's I'm trying to push. It's an intermittent issue as most of the logs are able to go through without any problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a field which shows up more than once, and gets interpreted as array ?

Comment: Figured it out, turns out the field did show up twice with different casing. :( Thanks.